# Помогите с проблемой при перезаписывании элемента в массиве C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Вот задание: В вещественном массиве X=(x1,x2,...,xn) каждую пару x[i] и x[j] (i,j=1,...,n; i<>j) отрицательных элементов преобразовать в положительные элементы по формуле x[i],x[j]:=sqrt(x[i]*x[j]). Пары элементов (i,j) выбирать в порядке их следования в массиве X.
Вот мое предполагаемое решение:

```
void Mass::change(){    
//int pos1 = 0;
//int pos2 = 0;
bool flag = false;
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    if (v[i] < 0) {
        int pos1 = 0;
        int pos2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            if (v[i] < 0) {
                flag = true;
                pos1 = i;
            }

            break;
        }

        for (int i = pos1 + 1; i < dim; i++) {
            if (v[i] < 0) {
                if (flag == true) {
                    pos2 = i;
                    v[pos1] = v[pos2] = sqrt(v[pos1] * v[pos2]);
                }

                else {
                    flag = true;
                    pos1 = i;
                }

                break;
            }

        }
        cout << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) cout << v[i] << " "; // вывожу измененный массив
        cout << "\n" << pos1 << pos2; // проверяю запись позиций
    }
}
```

Вот что выдает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас вложенные циклы используют одну и ту же переменную `i`. И какой смысл делать безусловный `break;` в конце цикла?

Comment: Потому,что в противном случае цикл доходит сразу до последнего элемента игнорируя остальные

Comment: Вы понимаете, что с тем же успехом могли бы вынуть код из цикла, поставив перед кодом `i=0`? Кроме того, остается проблема с одинаковой переменной для разных вложенных циклов...